# using Math.Floor

Tags: c#, math, floor

I am trying to use the `Math.Floor` method on 2 user-input numbers but whenever I try to use the `Math.Floor` with my `input3` and `input3a` it just doesn't work. I've seen examples for already set numbers such as in an array but not of numbers that the user inputs. Any help/clarification would be awesome.

```
static void Minimum()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n Enter two numbers and I shall determine the Minimum:\n");
        Console.Write("> ");
        Console.Write("\n> ");
        // Read and parse input
        string input3 = Console.ReadLine();
        double d_input3 = Double.Parse(input3.Trim());
        string input3a = Console.ReadLine();
        double d_input3a = Double.Parse(input3a.Trim());

        // Determine minimum of numbers

            Console.WriteLine("\nThe Number {0} and {1}.\n", d_input3, d_input3a);
    }
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? You don't explain what you're seeing or what you're expecting to see - and in fact you don't call `Math.Floor` in the code you've posted, so your question makes little sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "it just doesn't work"? What is the problem? You are not even using `Math.Floor` in the given sample code.

Comment: ah, I tried using it around the inputs, such as Math.Floor(d_input3, d_input3a)); and tried using it on the inputs seperately but to no avail.

Comment: I think you need to go an look [at the documentation for Math.Floor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor(v=vs.110).aspx), as it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you need the `Math.Min` method. If you'd posted your code and the error you're getting, you'd have had that response immediately. Alternatively, reading the documentation for the method you're calling would have had the same result...

Comment: Take a look at `Math.Min()` function instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If think you don't need [Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to determine a minimum :

> Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified
>   double-precision floating-point number.

If you need to determine the minimum of both numbers, use [Math.Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcd487wd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead

```
Console.WriteLine("\nThe minimum number between {0} and {1} is {2}.\n", d_input3, d_input3a, Math.Min(d_input3, d_input3a));
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you to other people who tried helping too, even the one's who were a bit rude >.>

Answer (score 1):

The `Math.Floor` function takes one parameter and returns the value rounded down:

```
d_input3 = Math.Floor(d_input3);
d_input3a = Math.Floor(d_input3a);
```

The `Math.Floor` method is however not used to determine the lower value of two values. For that you would use the `Math.Min` function instead:

```
double lowest = Math.Min(d_input3, d_input3a);
```

Comment: Returns what value? It returns the next integer below the passed value, which is not the OP's goal. This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Mh_Shiro: No, for that you would not use `Math.Floor` at all. I added code for that.